# Domain Matching using sed|awk

Tags: bash

I want to strip domains from list of urls.
The list of url's can contain random url data example:

```
hqtechvietnam.com/bcm943602cs-hackintosh-meedf/
hqxbcialyc.servequake.com
hqzjz7fncd.com
hraparak.org
hrcrossing.com
hrgenius-uk.com
hrms.prodigygroupindia.com
hrome-updater.ru
hrome-update.ru
hrowedinizoin.ru
hrydc.org
hsadjy30bjtnd.servecounterstrike.com
hsa.ht
HSBC Invest Direct Ltd
hs-fileserver.info
hslvizag.in
hssubnsx.xyz
htaminorfault.xyz
htempurl.com
http://185.102.122[]2/rrtn/Spencer crypt.exe
http://23.95.200195/image/images.exe
```

I'm currently using below shell script for sorting data

```
#PATTERN
URL_MATCH="(http|https|hxxp|hxxps)://[a-zA-Z0-9./?=_%:-]*"
DOMAIN_MATCH="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-.]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]+$"
IP_MATCH="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"

    CHK1 () {
        echo "Initiating Check process #1" |& GET_LOG
        while read -r DOMAINLIST;
        do 
    
        if grep -oqE "${IP_MATCH}" <<< "${DOMAINLIST}" 
            then 
                echo "${DOMAINLIST}" | grep -oE "${IP_MATCH}" >> "${IPOUT}" 
            elif  grep -oqE "${URL_MATCH}" <<< "${DOMAINLIST}"
                then
                    echo "${DOMAINLIST}" | awk -F \/ '{l=split($3,a,"."); print (a[l-1]=="com"?a[l-2] OFS:X) a[l-1] OFS a[l]}' OFS="." >> "${URLOUT}" 
            elif grep -oqE "${DOMAIN_MATCH}" <<< "${DOMAINLIST}"
                then 
                    echo "${DOMAINLIST}" | sed 's/.*\.\(\w*\.\w*\)/\1/' >> "${DOMAINOUT}"
            else
                echo "${DOMAINLIST}" >> "${ERROROUT}" 
            
        fi
        done < "${INFILE}"
    
    }
```

Above piece of code is currently doing the job okay, below is the result

```
URLOUT FILE:
hqzjz7fncd.com
hraparak.org
hrcrossing.com
hrgenius-uk.com
hrome-updater.ru
hrome-update.ru
hrowedinizoin.ru
hrydc.org
hsa.ht
hs-fileserver.info
hslvizag.in
hssubnsx.xyz
htaminorfault.xyz
htempurl.com
prodigygroupindia.com
servecounterstrike.com
servequake.com

ERROUT FILE:
hqtechvietnam.com/bcm943602cs-hackintosh-meedf/
HSBC Invest Direct Ltd
102.122[]2
```

But if the list of url contains data such as

```
google.co.uk 
example.co.in
https://example.co.au/file1
http://example.co.au/file1
```

It just gives me

```
co.uk
co.in
```

And I want

```
google.co.uk 
example.co.uk
example.co.au
```

Also if url's are

```
mail.google.com
example.com.uk
```

Expected output should be

```
google.com
example.com.uk
```

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output for your first list of 20+ URLs

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in bash with no external tools: [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```bash
shopt -s extglob

while read -r line; do
  # remove any leading http:// https:// hxxp:// hxxps://
  line=${line#h@(tt|xx)p?(s)://}

  # remove any trailing path
  line=${line%%/*}

  # print the line if it has at least one dot.
  [[ $line == *.* ]] && echo "$line"
done < file
```

With all your combined sample input:

```
hqtechvietnam.com
hqxbcialyc.servequake.com
hqzjz7fncd.com
hraparak.org
hrcrossing.com
hrgenius-uk.com
hrms.prodigygroupindia.com
hrome-updater.ru
hrome-update.ru
hrowedinizoin.ru
hrydc.org
hsadjy30bjtnd.servecounterstrike.com
hsa.ht
hs-fileserver.info
hslvizag.in
hssubnsx.xyz
htaminorfault.xyz
htempurl.com
185.102.122[]2
23.95.200195
google.co.uk
example.co.in
example.co.au
example.co.au
```